# Geocoder returned address

Tags: android, geocoding, google-geolocation

I am using `Geocoder` class to get Latitude and Longitude to from my String address that user types to `EditText`.

And what is interesting it returns results for such query as "q", "qq", "n", "N". Is there any way to make it better?(validate or something, or use another service?)

```
if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
          try {
                 List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(s.toString(), 4);
                            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                                Address userAddress = addresses.get(0);
                                double latitude = userAddress.getLatitude();
                                double longitude = userAddress.getLongitude();
                                mRestaurantLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                                if (userAddress != null) {
                                    mPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                } else {
                                    mPin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    mRestaurantLatLng = null;
                                }
                            } else {
                                mPin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mRestaurantLatLng = null;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use another Service directly, or you could prune your results for the detail level you want.

So like:

```
List<Address> results = GeoCoder.getFromLocationName(query, 100);
filter(results);
if (results.size() > 0) {
   // Do Stuff
}


....

void filter(List<Address> results) {
   for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
      Address address = results.get(i);
      if (!address.hasLatitude() || !address.hasLongitude()) {
          results.remove(i);
      }
      // remove any that dont match your desired detail level
      ...
}
```

Comment: Actually the address "q" has latitude and longitude.

Comment: Right but does it have other qualities. Lat and Long are easy. You can just pick a pair and it will cover enough area that it doesn't matter. But if you can actually get enough detailed address info then it might be a bit more what you are looking for. My point was more so add your own filtering based on your needs.

Comment: Yeah, if you would have some spare time try query places from my question. You would have street, city, even street number!